# Visiting a cemetery while pregnant with a future kohen?

Tags: halacha-theory, kohen-priest

My husband (a kohen) and I were discussing this the other day as a hypothetical.

While I know in general there's a minhag not to go to cemeteries while pregnant (I decided not to follow that), is there an actual issue if the mother knows the sex of the fetus and he will be a kohen?

Comment: How are you supposed to know? I don't think halachically we're supposed to go to doctors for that anyways, nor rely on that